# wordpress before or after javascript problem

Tags: jquery, javascript, slideshow

hi guys im aqeel im trying to implement a slide show in a wordpress site's home page but it not working it simply contains the `easyslider1.5.js` file which i put in js folder css which of course in css folder. Then i used

```
wp_register_script( 'slides', get_bloginfo('template_url')."/js/easySlider1.5.js" );
wp_enqueue_script('slides');
```

not worked then

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/easySlider1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i also used it with `get_bloginfo()` but did not work .... okay i am using them before

```
wp_head();
```

and the `jquery` code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#slider").easySlider({
         auto: true,
         continuous: true 
    });
   });  
</script>
```

and using it after `wp_head();`

but slide show is not working..... i am working on a project n i really need your help guys.

Comment: Hi Aqeel. To make it easier to read for people who want to answer or have the same problem: Could you please use code formatting and use upper-/lowercase letters? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason, why one should use [the proper hook](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/), which - in this case - is `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Then always keep in mind, that some plugins might require a dependency/are dependent on another Javascript library like jQuery.

Now this example shows you how to enqueue your script

- With the right path/URI API function
- With jQuery as dependency
- With a on-demand-caching version number (file name changes, when file contents changes and prevents browser caching in case of an update).
- Loads in the footer to speed up page loading

That's the **right** way of loading a script into a WordPress theme.

```
function wpse64374_register_slider_script()
{
    wp_enqueue_script(
         'easy-slider'
        ,get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/easySlider1.5.js"
        ,array( 'jquery )
        ,filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory()."/js/easySlider1.5.js" )
        ,true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse64374_register_slider_script' );
```

Comment: hi kaiser the code u suggested did not work .... i think our codes r righy there is some conflict between jQuery funtions or its loading it from some where else more than once.... well thnx alot for ur reply.

Comment: @Aqeel "did not work" is no proper problem/error description. Please elaborate. And also: Please go back and rework your question - see comment on question.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in current theme's functions.php file

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'easyslider_function');
function easyslider_function(){
     if(is_home()){ // assume you want to show slider only Home page. if you set static front page then use  is_front_page() in condition.
         wp_register_script( 'easyslider_js', get_bloginfo('template_url')."/js/easySlider1.5.js" );           
         wp_enqueue_script('easyslider_js');
         echo 'jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#slider").easySlider({ auto: true, continuous: true }); });';
     }
    }
```

FYI: make sure you are using correct id as a slider container.

Hope this code helps you. All the best ;)

Comment: Use `wp_enqueue_scripts` not `wp_head`.

Comment: actually, according to Aqeel's question may be he wants to use script in header file that's why I used wp_head.

Comment: Aqeel, if my answer useful for you then vote and accept my answer. thanks

Comment: As @Joseph already said: `wp_head` is the wrong hook. Use `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead.

Comment: hi techguy ....... thnx alot for ur reply but i think prob is somewhere is conflict of jQuery and i think its getting loaded twice.......  well thnx again. im trying to solve the issue. but its still creating prob for me.

Comment: Hi Aqeel, if my answer helps you, please vote. Thanks